# store line data into array - bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to save specific data into arrays, i have a file of this structure :

```
field1 field2 field3 fields4 fields5 200
field6 field7 field8 fields9 fields10 520
```

line by line, each field seperated only by one space
what i need is an array that will contain only the field in the 3rd and 6th field, i.e first array will have: (field3 , field8) ans second will have: (200, 520)
what i tried was this:

```
        thirdFields=$(sort $1 | cut -d " " -f3)
        sixthField=$(sort $1 | cut -d " " -f6)
```

well, sort of. 
(after that i need to find the max of them, that's why im sorting it).

thanks a bunch guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to what you already have, so I'm not sure if this is what you want. It extracts the desired field from each line, then sorts the output before storing it in the array.

```
thirdFields=( $( cut -d' ' -f3 file | sort) )
sixthFields=( $( cut -d' ' -f6 file | sort) )
```

Comment: that's graet. thanks!
and as for the other solutions - i forgot to mention im not allowed to use awk
but thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. Let the file name be `file`

```
a=(`awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "}{print $3}' file | sort`)
b=(`awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "}{print $6}' file | sort`)
```

Answer (score 0):

with bash

```
$ while read -a fields; do f3+=(${fields[2]}); f6+=(${fields[5]}); done <<END
field1 field2 field3 fields4 fields5 200
field6 field7 field8 fields9 fields10 520
END
$ printf "%s\n" "${f3[@]}"
field3
field8
$ printf "%s\n" "${f6[@]}"
200
520
$ sorted=( $(printf "%s\n" "${f6[@]}" | sort -n) )
$ echo "min: ${sorted[0]}"
$ echo "max: ${sorted[-1]}"
```